After upgrading to Cassandra 5, Nodes keep going out of schema sync and seeing each other as Down (gossip issues)
We have a 2 node cluster (I know 3 is the recommended minimum) which had been running Cassandra 3 and then 4 for years without incident.
Last week we upgraded both nodes to Cassandra 5.
Since then, the nodes have been having what seems like gossip and communication issues. Especially when the schema is updated (like when creating or deleting a table).
Here is the debug log right after making a schema change (deleteing a table):
INFO  [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2024-11-03 09:48:04,021 Keyspace.java:379 - Creating replication strategy r_internal params KeyspaceParams{durable_writes=true, replication=ReplicationParams{class=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy, replication_factor=2}}
DEBUG [Native-Transport-Requests-1] 2024-11-03 09:48:04,064 MigrationCoordinator.java:430 - Reported schema a47919aa-79b3-362c-b023-d8ac89671885 at endpoint /10.10.2.27:7000
DEBUG [MigrationStage:1] 2024-11-03 09:48:04,070 MigrationCoordinator.java:749 - Pushing schema mutations: [Mutation(keyspace='system_schema', key='72617976656e5f696e7465726e616c', modifications=[
  [system_schema.columns] key=r_internal partition_deletion=deletedAt=-9223372036854775808, localDeletion=9223372036854775807 columns=[[] | []]
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=cdate |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=device_id |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=event_timestamp |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=info |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=input |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=node_id |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=output |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=server |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=unique_flow_process |
  [system_schema.indexes] key=r_internal partition_deletion=deletedAt=-9223372036854775808, localDeletion=9223372036854775807 columns=[[] | []]
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, index_name=p1489_log_node_input_output_unique_flow_process_idx |
  [system_schema.keyspaces] key=r_internal partition_deletion=deletedAt=-9223372036854775808, localDeletion=9223372036854775807 columns=[[] | [durable_writes replication]]
    Row[info=[ts=1730627238890000] ]: EMPTY | [durable_writes=true ts=1730627238890000], [replication=0000000200000005636c6173730000002b6f72672e6170616368652e63617373616e6472612e6c6f6361746f722e53696d706c655374726174656779000000127265706c69636174696f6e5f666163746f720000000132 ts=1730627238890000]
  [system_schema.tables] key=r_internal partition_deletion=deletedAt=-9223372036854775808, localDeletion=9223372036854775807 columns=[[] | []]
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output |
])]
DEBUG [MigrationStage:1] 2024-11-03 09:48:04,071 MigrationCoordinator.java:757 - Pushing schema mutations to /10.10.2.28:7000: [Mutation(keyspace='system_schema', key='72617976656e5f696e7465726e616c', modifications=[
  [system_schema.columns] key=r_internal partition_deletion=deletedAt=-9223372036854775808, localDeletion=9223372036854775807 columns=[[] | []]
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=cdate |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=device_id |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=event_timestamp |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=info |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=input |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=node_id |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=output |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=server |
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, column_name=unique_flow_process |
  [system_schema.indexes] key=r_internal partition_deletion=deletedAt=-9223372036854775808, localDeletion=9223372036854775807 columns=[[] | []]
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output, index_name=p1489_log_node_input_output_unique_flow_process_idx |
  [system_schema.keyspaces] key=r_internal partition_deletion=deletedAt=-9223372036854775808, localDeletion=9223372036854775807 columns=[[] | [durable_writes replication]]
    Row[info=[ts=1730627238890000] ]: EMPTY | [durable_writes=true ts=1730627238890000], [replication=0000000200000005636c6173730000002b6f72672e6170616368652e63617373616e6472612e6c6f6361746f722e53696d706c655374726174656779000000127265706c69636174696f6e5f666163746f720000000132 ts=1730627238890000]
  [system_schema.tables] key=r_internal partition_deletion=deletedAt=-9223372036854775808, localDeletion=9223372036854775807 columns=[[] | []]
    Row[info=[ts=-9223372036854775808] del=deletedAt=1730627238890000, localDeletion=1730627238 ]: table_name=p1489_log_node_input_output |
])]
ERROR [GossipStage:1] 2024-11-03 09:48:04,187 JVMStabilityInspector.java:70 - Exception in thread Thread[GossipStage:1,5,GossipStage]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AssertionError
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundSink.accept(InboundSink.java:108)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundSink.accept(InboundSink.java:45)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundMessageHandler$ProcessMessage.run(InboundMessageHandler.java:430)
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.ExecutionFailure$1.run(ExecutionFailure.java:133)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: null
        at org.apache.cassandra.db.TypeSizes.sizeof(TypeSizes.java:44)
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.VersionedValue$VersionedValueSerializer.serializedSize(VersionedValue.java:365)
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.VersionedValue$VersionedValueSerializer.serializedSize(VersionedValue.java:343)
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.EndpointStateSerializer.serializedSize(EndpointState.java:344)
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.EndpointStateSerializer.serializedSize(EndpointState.java:300)
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.GossipDigestAckSerializer.serializedSize(GossipDigestAck.java:96)
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.GossipDigestAckSerializer.serializedSize(GossipDigestAck.java:61)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.Message$Serializer.payloadSize(Message.java:1088)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.Message.payloadSize(Message.java:1131)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.Message$Serializer.serializedSize(Message.java:769)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.Message.serializedSize(Message.java:1111)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundConnections.connectionTypeFor(OutboundConnections.java:215)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundConnections.connectionFor(OutboundConnections.java:207)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundConnections.enqueue(OutboundConnections.java:96)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.doSend(MessagingService.java:473)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.OutboundSink.accept(OutboundSink.java:70)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.send(MessagingService.java:462)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.send(MessagingService.java:437)
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.GossipDigestSynVerbHandler.doVerb(GossipDigestSynVerbHandler.java:110)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundSink.lambda$new$0(InboundSink.java:78)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundSink.accept(InboundSink.java:97)
        ... 7 common frames omitted
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2024-11-03 09:48:04,187 HeapUtils.java:133 - Heap dump creation on uncaught exceptions is disabled.
DEBUG [GossipStage:1] 2024-11-03 09:48:04,187 HeapUtils.java:133 - Heap dump creation on uncaught exceptions is disabled.

The exception Exception in thread Thread[GossipStage:1,5,GossipStage] keeps repeating itself over and over.
At this point running nodetool status shows each one thinking the other is down

I usually need to drain and restart both nodes (which I do one after the other) for them both to see each other and show their schemas are in sync.
Here is the output of nodetool gossipinfo (after restarting the nodes)
/10.10.2.27
  generation:1730627829
  heartbeat:939
  STATUS:23:NORMAL,-1656170799351181049
  LOAD:898:2.029075780322E12
  SCHEMA:17:a47919aa-79b3-362c-b023-d8ac89671885
  DC:13:dc1
  RACK:15:rack1
  RELEASE_VERSION:6:5.0.2
  INTERNAL_IP:11:10.10.2.27
  RPC_ADDRESS:5:10.10.2.27
  NET_VERSION:2:12
  HOST_ID:3:8be5925c-0436-4bc7-bd4c-0fb5dd8fc9e5
  RPC_READY:35:true
  INTERNAL_ADDRESS_AND_PORT:9:10.10.2.27:7000
  NATIVE_ADDRESS_AND_PORT:4:10.10.2.27:9042
  STATUS_WITH_PORT:22:NORMAL,-1656170799351181049
  SSTABLE_VERSIONS:7:big-nb
  TOKENS:21:<hidden>
/10.10.2.28
  generation:1730628138
  heartbeat:619
  LOAD:586:2.215579324507E12
  SCHEMA:17:a47919aa-79b3-362c-b023-d8ac89671885
  DC:13:dc1
  RACK:15:rack1
  RELEASE_VERSION:6:5.0.2
  NET_VERSION:2:12
  HOST_ID:3:c9e8a4f8-c7b2-4cac-994a-e8de50c9f358
  RPC_READY:35:true
  INTERNAL_ADDRESS_AND_PORT:9:10.10.2.28:7000
  NATIVE_ADDRESS_AND_PORT:4:10.10.2.28:9042
  STATUS_WITH_PORT:22:NORMAL,-2024247660995288657
  SSTABLE_VERSIONS:7:big-nb
  TOKENS:21:<hidden>

And here from the second node
/10.10.2.27
  generation:1730627829
  heartbeat:906
  LOAD:898:2.029075780322E12
  SCHEMA:17:a47919aa-79b3-362c-b023-d8ac89671885
  DC:13:dc1
  RACK:15:rack1
  RELEASE_VERSION:6:5.0.2
  NET_VERSION:2:12
  HOST_ID:3:8be5925c-0436-4bc7-bd4c-0fb5dd8fc9e5
  RPC_READY:35:true
  INTERNAL_ADDRESS_AND_PORT:9:10.10.2.27:7000
  NATIVE_ADDRESS_AND_PORT:4:10.10.2.27:9042
  STATUS_WITH_PORT:22:NORMAL,-1656170799351181049
  SSTABLE_VERSIONS:7:big-nb
  TOKENS:21:<hidden>
/10.10.2.28
  generation:1730628138
  heartbeat:584
  STATUS:23:NORMAL,-2024247660995288657
  LOAD:524:2.215537773956E12
  SCHEMA:17:a47919aa-79b3-362c-b023-d8ac89671885
  DC:13:dc1
  RACK:15:rack1
  RELEASE_VERSION:6:5.0.2
  INTERNAL_IP:11:10.10.2.28
  RPC_ADDRESS:5:10.10.2.28
  NET_VERSION:2:12
  HOST_ID:3:c9e8a4f8-c7b2-4cac-994a-e8de50c9f358
  RPC_READY:35:true
  INTERNAL_ADDRESS_AND_PORT:9:10.10.2.28:7000
  NATIVE_ADDRESS_AND_PORT:4:10.10.2.28:9042
  STATUS_WITH_PORT:22:NORMAL,-2024247660995288657
  SSTABLE_VERSIONS:7:big-nb
  TOKENS:21:<hidden>

When they are having issues this is what nodetool gossinfo shows when run on 10.10.2.28:
/10.10.2.27
  generation:1730626480
  heartbeat:810
  LOAD:771:2.029304184276E12
  SCHEMA:17:9bcfb867-92ca-3144-92d7-da5fed3359d0
  DC:13:dc1
  RACK:15:rack1
  RELEASE_VERSION:6:5.0.2
  NET_VERSION:2:12
  HOST_ID:3:8be5925c-0436-4bc7-bd4c-0fb5dd8fc9e5
  RPC_READY:35:true
  INTERNAL_ADDRESS_AND_PORT:9:10.10.2.27:7000
  NATIVE_ADDRESS_AND_PORT:4:10.10.2.27:9042
  STATUS_WITH_PORT:22:NORMAL,-1656170799351181049
  SSTABLE_VERSIONS:7:big-nb
  TOKENS:21:<hidden>
/10.10.2.28
  generation:1730625184
  heartbeat:2523
  STATUS:23:NORMAL,-2024247660995288657
  LOAD:2513:2.214202366182E12
  SCHEMA:2243:a47919aa-79b3-362c-b023-d8ac89671885
  DC:13:dc1
  RACK:15:rack1
  RELEASE_VERSION:6:5.0.2
  INTERNAL_IP:11:10.10.2.28
  RPC_ADDRESS:5:10.10.2.28
  NET_VERSION:2:12
  HOST_ID:3:c9e8a4f8-c7b2-4cac-994a-e8de50c9f358
  RPC_READY:35:true
  INTERNAL_ADDRESS_AND_PORT:9:10.10.2.28:7000
  NATIVE_ADDRESS_AND_PORT:4:10.10.2.28:9042
  STATUS_WITH_PORT:22:NORMAL,-2024247660995288657
  SSTABLE_VERSIONS:7:big-nb
  INDEX_STATUS:2198:{"r_internal.p1643_log_node_input_output_unique_flow_process_idx":"BUILD_SUCCEEDED","r_internal.p1720_log_node_input_output_unique_flow_process_idx":"BUILD_SUCCEEDED","r_internal.p1479_log_node_input_output_unique_flow_process_idx":"BUILD_SUCCEEDED"...}
  TOKENS:21:<hidden>


One thing that stands out to me, is the differences in the DC and Rack names. The gossip info shows it as dc1 and rack1, while the screenshot shows it as dc1/rack1 for one node and DC1/r1 for another. Was one node given the incorrect DC/Rack names on accident, and somehow changed after-the-fact? That would certainly cause some "weirdness."

I noticed that too but just assumed that as long as the other server was DN then it didn't know what rack it was and r1 was a default... In any case, the cassandra-rackdc.properties file on both servers have dc=dc1 and rack=rack1. If they started as r1 and then were changed to rack1 what needs to be done or how can I check this?

I'm trying to think of where that would be persisted, but most likely in the system.local of that node, and on the system.peers of the other. Actually, the system.peers table is built from gossip, so you can safely truncate it and let it rebuilt itself. TBH though, the only way to "fix" a node originally given a bad DC/Rack name is to decommission and re-join it.

Thanks @Aaron We actually spoke to someone who works on Cassandra who opened a ticket, and it appears like an issue in Cassandra itself and our large number of tables https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-20058

Oh yikes! Wow, that's definitely an issue. Thanks for passing that along.
